# How to use the Ledger Nano S hardware wallet without installing Chrome?

Tags: wallets, security, ledger-nano-s

How can I use the Ledger Nano S hardware wallet with FOSS only and hence without having to install Google Chrome on my Debian machine?

I'd like to use for it ethereum and altcoins.

Answer (score 2):

My Ether Wallet should still work without any Chrome (or extensions).

I use it with Firefox, not tested with Ledger Nano S.

[Source with step-by-step instrucitons](https://ledger.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115005200009-How-to-use-MyEtherWallet-with-Ledger). They specifically mention that you don't need to use Chrome if you use MEW.

As always, beware of phishing.